# Querying data in MySQL Geometry data type column

Tags: mysql, geometry, gis, shapefile

I have a table that stores polygons in a GEOMETRY data type column that I loaded via a shapefile using ogr2ogr. Here's the create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sunzones` (
  `OGR_FID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `polygon` geometry NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `OGR_FID` (`OGR_FID`),
  SPATIAL KEY `polygon` (`polygon`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=105 ;
```

Here is a sample record:

```
POLYGON((449455.354522821 2447255.57758461,449700.419971925 2447132.08575524,449970.797988416 2447012.08302579,450331.302189915 2446845.08750142,450720.557402377 2446631.12366577,451001.686314893 2446471.65633497,451351.253709065 2446236.2071619,451621.320850174 2445889.34918971,451822.94912776 2445643.44939179,451970.329536186 2445268.16443891,451900.90187755 2444641.13680345,451762.850153972 2443964.1640728,451483.986510987 2443208.22160261,451201.806260121 2442650.10616671,451020.687327243 2442095.95148262,450839.505763005 2441544.78980207,450683.636511575 2441015.10597334,450538.454805135 2440413.89081544,450433.333155727 2440035.55620047,450360.648999258 2439678.70563045,450288.151292623 2439419.31682052,450118.029551282 2439008.99974342,449901.03211162 2438634.67295293,449702.407549484 2438469.26337817,449341.345080443 2438239.89817619,449070.656839706 2438139.47157292,448886.71805136 2438143.99566917,448634.339635752 2438227.50240038,448385.707435195 2438433.96784289,448234.638650137 2438747.88628722,448145.380437968 2439372.19635416,448095.562049752 2439852.04892374,447984.553987549 2440439.87931978,447808.669818343 2441024.70524153,447592.724965448 2441364.09711298,447275.840595988 2441754.49255107,447067.208249397 2442148.36776757,446617.319564483 2442841.67896542,446426.750106166 2443289.53943803,446257.992375297 2443841.82345023,446157.983746886 2444530.46142231,446014.475379242 2445071.69774818,445881.655839275 2445515.48887139,445748.650167696 2445843.84709753,445669.894930651 2446244.64998972,445684.828488262 2446608.40816774,445779.199887883 2446997.59260231,445887.760935538 2447234.8818733,446155.073525621 2447526.07468538,446451.07445614 2447654.87106738,446714.451262744 2447697.24267349,446959.766023142 2447696.15327556,447233.893916706 2447670.07230515,447450.271461094 2447633.52082824,448020.090403634 2447559.36967915,448377.094925486 2447485.7971982,448943.225936908 2447365.18349843,449455.354522821 2447255.57758461))
```

Which was queried using:

```
SELECT ASTEXT( POLYGON ) FROM  `sunzones`;
```

I've got a specific latitude and longitude, and I want to know which records have polygons that encompass that lat/lng, so I've tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sunzones WHERE MBRWithin(GeomFromText('Point(21.3069 -157.8583)'), polygon);
```

but that returns no records. I even tried to convert the lat/lng to UTM coordinates, but this query also returns no records:

```
SELECT * FROM sunzones WHERE MBRWithin(GeomFromText('Point(2447696.15327556 447233.893916706)'), polygon);
```

Is there something wrong with my queries?

I'm using MySQL 5.6, by the way. Also, I've tried ST_CONTAINS() and CONTAINS(), as well.

*Note, the coordinates in the queries don't necessarily fall inside of the single sample polygon that I posted above. The shapes are all in Hawaii, so my lat/lng is just Honolulu's coordinates.*

Answer (score 6):

After spending way too long messing with this, I came up with the right syntax for the query:

```
SELECT * FROM sunzones WHERE MBRWITHIN( POINT( 863575.082797506, 2137306.79465704 ) , polygon )
```

The important things to note here are that the coordinates are reversed (longitude/latitude, not latitude/longitude), and unlike most examples posted, I didn't have to use GeomFromText() to declare the Point.

Comment: the standard is to have point(long,lat) for sharing geometries