# Fetching MySQL Geo Point Data and storing result in PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

My goal is to insert some point data into a MySQL database. I populated the database with some dummy data and it seems to work. Later, I would like to retrieve that data and store it in a PHP variable so I can post an html table of the data.

```
  Point   X   Y
   P1     1   1
   P2     4   2
```

Note: Please don't hate on the "art".

I am using the following query string to retrieve the data from the MySQL database. I've used this code in non-point based data and have no problems, things run just fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->tableName . " WHERE `OTHER` = '" . $Otherdata . "' AND `POSITION` = 'POINT(1,1)' LIMIT 0, 30 ";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    //print_r($row);//This is empty, or null...which means my $sql line is wrong too...

    $Index = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $this->PositionX[$Index] = $row['POSITION']; //Error must be HERE!                  
        $this->PositionY[$Index] = $row['POSITION']; // How do I access .X() or [0] or whatever it 
        $this->OtherVariable[$Index] = $row['OTHER']; // is that points to the first element of Point?
        $Index++;
    }
```

Long story short, this doesn't work. $row['POSITION'] has no idea that I want the X component. Also $row is null or empty, which means my $sql must not be correct.

**Question 1:**

What is the correct way of checking if a Point(x,y) is equal to some point in the DB in MySQL?

**Edit:** Found an answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373982/querying-data-in-mysql-geometry-data-type-column). The 'POINT(1,1)' part of the query should actually just be POINT(1,1) that is, without the **'** characters. The correct line reads:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->tableName . " WHERE `OTHER` = '" . $Otherdata . "' AND `POSITION` = POINT(1,1) LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

**Question 2:**

What is the syntax to retrieve a piece of point data from a MySQL database and store it the X and Y components, in a PHP Variable? (Technically two php variables, one for X and one for Y, but you know what I mean.)

Another way to word it, how can I call `echo $row['POSITION'];` (for X and Y independently)?

Comment: A few things: 1. Quoting from the manual (for the function `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`): `Returns an associative array of strings representing the fetched row in the result set, where each key in the array represents the name of one of the result set's columns or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.` - this means that your SQL-query doesn't have to be wrong... 2. Your code is vulnerable to "SQL-injection" 3. To check if your query is wrong or not, you can preferably use `var_dump($query)`", and give us the result.

Comment: Regarding the sql injection, I removed a lot of code in order to isolate my point. Also var_dump will be quite helpful, thanks. In fact I had more bugs/errors than I thought. I did manage a fix, posted below, and I'd be happy to have any critiques.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using the the `As` keyword.

```
"SELECT X(`POSITION`) as Xpos, Y(`POSITION`) as Ypos, `Other1`, `Other2`, `Other3`, `Other4` FROM " . $this->tableName . " WHERE `Other4` = '" . $Otherdata . ";
```

This let me access just one component of the Point.

```
$myXpos = $row['Xpos'];
$myYpos = $row['Ypos'];
```

Thus accessing the X and Y components of a Point data type object independently.

Answer (score 6):

I've recently been dealing with the same problem and whilst the above method does work, for anybody who would like to extract the coordinates from a binary data blob (as received from 'fetch_assoc' for example), then this method should work:

```
function rawPointToFloatPair($data)
{   
    $res = unpack("lSRID/CByteOrder/lTypeInfo/dX/dY", $data);
    return [$res['X'],$res['Y']];
}
```

The data structure features 4 bytes as an ID, followed by a byte to define byte order (0  = big endian, 1 = little endian. Not handled here for brevity) and then 4 bytes for 'integer information' (where a value of '1' means this is a point). 
The next 16 bytes are two double precision floating point numbers.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for... could you please update your answer to include the source of your information? Where did you find the structure of the returned data?